# Mapping Debian user to generic Windows SID

Tags: ntfs, ntfs-3g

Suppose I have a user `win` on Debian (9.3, ntfs-3g/stable,now 1:2016.2.22AR.1+dfsg-1 amd64 [installed]). I would like this user to be mapped to `S-1-5-19` (which is the generic SID for LOCAL_SERVICE on Windows). My `\.NTFS-3G\UserMapping` looks like this:

```
www-data:www-data:S-1-5-19
```

But during mounting I get an error: 
"There were no valid user or no valid group."

If I replace the generic SID with a `S-1-5-21-<domain>-XXX` one, the error goes away. Why is this? Am I not able to map UNIX users to generic SIDs?